# Где реализовать функционал логирования запросов?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, flask, fastapi

Вечер добрый!

У меня есть функиция, которая отвечает за работу endpoint **/search**. Там описана реализация поиска некоего контента в базе данных и его возврата в ответе, в случае, наличия.
Но в данный момент захотелось сделать так, чтобы при обращении к **/search**, сервер,перед выполнением уже реализованного кода, смотрел в еще одной базе данных наличие записи с таким запросом. В случае отсутствия создавал запись, а в случае наличия записи по такому запросу, обновлял эту запись. (Другими словами хочется вести статистику по количеству запросов по каждому значению)

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать данный функционал:

- через **Depends** вызывать какую-то функцию, которая будет делать это всё. Но не совсем уверен что можно передать внутрь неё значения получаемые в обработчик endpoint
- Через **Middleware** парсить каждый запрос, и в случае обращения к **/search** делать запись/редактирование в бд
- Тупо написать всё внутри обработчика эндпоинта **/search**, прям перед реализацией поиска

Использую FastApi и MongoDB. Может есть какой-то более правильный способ, который общепринят ? 
 Спасибо!

Структура записи в бд, которая хранит поисковый запрос и пользователей, которые искали его:

```
{
"request" : "собачки",
"users" : [{"UserID" : "12311", "Searches": 1}],
"firstSearch" : "31.02.2022",
"lastSearch" : "31.02.2222"
}
```

Comment: А что представляет из себя запись в другой базе, не совсем понял что значит статистика по кол-ву запросов по каждому значению. Значение это результат поиска? Если ты хочешь записать результат, то почему пишешь чтобы он ходил до выполнения запроса?

Comment: Возможно криво описал идею, извиняюсь. Не особо важно, когда будет выполнено это "логирование".  Оно всего лишь будет хранить запрос ( именно поисковый запрос ), информацию о пользователе и даты первого и последнего поиска по этому запросу от всех пользователей.